# how to assert key in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have trouble with assert keys in my code.

```
No keyword with name 'in {'name': '$.data[0].name'}' found.
```

my code is

```
*** Variables ***
&{name}    name=$.data[0].name

*** Variables ***
Run keyword if  'name'  in ${name}  log  name is in the log as expected
```

Comment: This can't be your real code. You don't have a test case table, you have two variable tables.  This code won't give the error you have in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've defined your test cases (assuming the second `*** Variables ***` is actually `*** Test Cases ***`), robot thinks `Run keyword if` is the name of a test case, and the first keyword is `'name' in ${name}`

The solution is to give your test case a name.

There's also a problem that you have two spaces after `'name'` which should give you a different error than what you're reporting. Also, the second table should be named `*** Test Cases ***`.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example test case
    Run keyword if  'name' in ${name}  log  name is in the log as expected
```

You should probably also use `$name` rather than `${name}` so that robot injects the actual variable into the expression.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example test case
    Run keyword if  'name' in $name  log  name is in the log as expected
```